# What algorithm does core ml use?

Tags: swift, xcode, coreml

I have searched it everywhere but couldn’t end up with an solid answer. My question is what machine learning algorithm does core ml use? How do I answer to that question?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://coremltools.readme.io/docs/what-are-coreml-tools#supported-libraries-and-frameworks):

> Core ML supports a variety of machine learning models, including
> neural networks, tree ensembles, support vector machines, and
> generalized linear models.